# Face Recognition using java with images or pictures

Tags: java, opencv, face-detection, face-recognition

I am working on a Face recognition Project based on java.

These are the pre-processing steps I use:

1. I was done with the face detection using openCV in java.
   The Link I used for face detection is: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/opencv/opencv_face_detection_in_picture.htm

After Detecting the face of a particular person in an image or picture, I want to recognise the same face in another images or pictures. So that I can collect or grouped all the images of that particular person in an seperate folder.

For Face recognition I also checked the eigenface recogniser of opencv and it mainly has the implementation for the real time face detection and recognistion using web cam.

To do so I googled and found CognitiveJ - Image Analysis in Java from GitHub.
   Link for that is :https://github.com/CognitiveJ/cognitivej
   also go through the videos : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WmzrKXWfa2o

But its chargeable, so doesn't work for me.

I also tried FAINT but it would not met my expectation as it has many plugins which specifically worked on windows OS and I am using Ubuntu.
  https://faint.sourceforge.io/

So please suggest, how to group the images of particular person into a seperate folder from the folder in which many images are present along with the images of that particular person using java. So that I implement that code into my application.